# Is there an equivalent MATLAB dec2bin function in Fortran?

Tags: matlab, binary, fortran, decimal

I would like to find a similar function as `dec2bin(d,n)` in MATLAB, which produces a binary representation with at least `n` bits, for Fortran. Online I found [this code](https://fr.scribd.com/doc/207122116/Program-to-Do-Decimal-to-Binary-Conversion-in-Fortran), which converts decimal to binary but without a mechanism to decide the number of bits, and it asks for the user to decide whether its a positive integer or a positive real number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the `B` edit operator (as per High Performance Mark's comment), that requires a fairly recent compiler.

```
!> Returns a binary representation of d as a string with at least n bits. 
!> abs(d) < 2^52
function dec2bin(d, n)
  implicit none
  integer,intent(in)            :: d
  integer,intent(in),optional   :: n
  character(len=:),allocatable  :: dec2bin
  character(len=53)             :: tmp
  integer                       :: n_
  character(len=8)              :: f

  if (present(n)) then
    n_ = min(n, 53)
    write(f,'(i2)') n_
    f = '(B' // trim(adjustl(f)) // '.' // trim(adjustl(f)) // ')'
  else
    f = '(B53)'
  endif

  write(tmp,f) d
  dec2bin = trim(adjustl(tmp))
end function
```

Note that this function does not check the sign (as the sign is correctly handled). If you want to limit this to positive integers, you need to do it outside the function.

---

Just because I had to look for the correct syntax myself, here are the relevant sections from the Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 10.7.2.4 "B, O, and Z editing":

> 1 The Bw , Bw .m, Ow , Ow .m, Zw , and Zw .m edit descriptors indicate that the field to be edited occupies w
>   positions, except when w is zero. When w is zero, the processor selects the field width. On input, w shall not be
>   zero. The corresponding input/output list item shall be of type integer, real, or complex.
>
> [...]
>
> 6 The output field for the Bw .m, Ow .m, and Zw .m edit descriptor is the same as for the Bw, Ow, and Zw edit descriptor, except that the digit-string or hex-digit-string consists of at least m digits. If necessary, sufficient
>   leading zeros are included to achieve the minimum of m digits. The value of m shall not exceed the value of w ,
>   except when w is zero. [...]